# Xamarin Form: What is different between the two filename-Signed.apk and filename.apk

Tags: android, xamarin, apk, signed

I have archived my android project and it create two files after Sign and Distribute. One have Signed.apk at the end. What are the difference between the two. I think one is signed but not the other.

The filename-SIGNED.apk can load my splash screen and end up crashed. The one filename.apk have no problem showing after go into splash screen.

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at the file sizes. Most likely the signed APK is of a smaller size. This is because of a bug I have noticed as well where the signed apk isn’t formed properly and hence causes the crash.

What’s the purpose/difference between the two? If you try to install the apk file that is unsigned, you will have to first give permission in the android device settings to allow installation of untrusted application files.

Comment: Do u know how to fix or even see what is going

Comment: There could be a ton of reasons it’s crashing. I would suggest recording a log of everything going on your device and then scroll through and read what exception is raised.